# Text style on chronometer on android

Tags: android, chronometer

How do I change the font ans font size on chronometer. When I align the chronometer with a textview it shows different size and settings. I also tried assigning font settings from textview.

```
chronometer.setTypeface(txtView.getTypeface());
chronometer.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,txtView.getTextSize());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the font style and font size on chronometer using following

**XML**

```
android:typeface="serif"
android:textSize="120dp"
```

in xml you can set default fonts of android.

**JAVA**

```
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/opensanslight.ttf");

        focus = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer1);
        focus.setTypeface(font, Typeface.NORMAL);
        focus.setTextSize(120);
```

where focus is chronometer.

> **for custom fonts**

put your **.ttf** files in assets folder.

in **android studio**
you have to create assets folder under  **src/main/assets/**

Comment: Thanks for your response, but is it possible to assign font settings from a textview in the same layout pragmatically ? I dont want to add any ttf files as long as all controls use similar font settings.

Comment: Yes it is possible first set typeface from xml or programatically.then **tv2.setTypeface(tv1.getTypeface());** of set a common typeface and use it in all program.